# How to total values in VBA and put that value into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how to total values in VBA and put it into a cell.

I got:

```
Dim client As Range, totalPrice As Range, dDate As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, subT As Double

Set client = Range("A2:A32")

i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
subT = 0

For Each cell In client

    If cell(i, 1) = "apple" Then

        If cell(j, 3) >= 43191 And cell(j, 3) <= 43220 Then
            subT = subT + cell(k, 5)
        End If

    End If

    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 1

Next

Cells(10, 10).Value = subT

End Sub
```

The table has 5 columns (column 1 is fruit name, column 3 is date, and column 5 is price) and there are total of 32 rows.

I'm trying to get April 2018 prices for "apple". There are two apples in April, but the subT variable only stores the first one (it skips the price value at row 32).

Row 1 is headers.
Row 26 has a price for apple of 42.09 (it stores this and prints it).
Row 31 has a price for apple of 14.65 (it does not store this and does not add it to subT).

Comment: I found the solution but I don't understand why it works. I added another Range called all (which is the whole table including headers) and change my initial values of i,j,k to 2 instead...and it worked! I also changed "cell" to "Cells", but I'm not sure if that matters. I'm glad I figured it out but can somebody explain why this is?

Comment: Cells is the collection of all cells in the active worksheet, and cell is a cell in the client range because you said 'For Each cell In client'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, you were iterating through the range but also using the offset method of a range object.

First things first, 'cell' is leads to horrible confusion as a variable name in Excel VBA.

That said:

cell(x,y) is the offset method. It means get me the range that is x - 1 rows down and y - 1 columns right from whatever range is referenced by cell.

The for each loop is automatically updating the range referenced by the variable cell, traversing from A2 to A32 in order. And your i,j,k variables are instructing the program to check ranges that are increasingly offset from your table.

For example in the first pass cell references A2 and cell(i,1) references A2. In the second pass cell references A3 (for each updated this) and cell(i,1) references A4 (i=2 and the offset method says give me the range offset one row down from A3). In the third pass cell references A4 and cell(i=3,1) references A6! (since A6 is offset 3 - 1 =2 rows from A4) and so on.

It's not clear to me why initializing i,j,k to 2 allowed things to work. I suspect that was an accident. The Cells method always offsets from A1 (I believe) so I don't think that helps anything.

My suggestion would be to get rid of i,j and k altogether:

```
    If cell(1, 1) = "apple" Then

    If cell(1, 3) >= 43191 And cell(1, 3) <= 43220 Then
    subT = subT + cell(1, 5)
```

They're not doing you any favors.

I hope this helps.